# Init mock database before all tests

Tags: c#, sqlite, unit-testing, nunit, parameter-passing

I use `HttpSelfHostServer` to build a RESTful API that uses SQLite database.
I use `Moq` assembly to mock my database.

Using `Nunit` I write a `TestFixture` with `SetUp` method, which construct `MockDatabaseContext`. And I have couple tests, that use this `MockDatabaseContext`.

Now I want to use `MockDatabaseContext` in all my tests in the test project.

I read article that says:

> "...A SetUpFixture outside of any namespace provides SetUp and
>   TearDown for the entire assembly..."

I moved my `SetUp` method to another class `Init`, which is placed in no-namespace, and changed attribute to `OneTimeSetUp`. That setup's method worked perfectly only one time before running all tests in the assembly as I want.

But the `OneTimeSetUp` method construct `MockDatabaseContext` inside not static `Init` class. ***How can i pass created `MockDatabaseContext` to all other tests, which all started after `OneTimeSetUp`?***

```
[SetUpFixture]
public class Init
{
    public Mock<MyDBContext> MockDatabaseContext

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void OneTimeSetUpMethod()
    {
        MockDatabaseContext = SomeFunctionConstructsMockedContext();
    }
}

namespace All.My.Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class TestFixture1
    {
        [TestCase]
        public void Test1() {/* Here i want to be able using MockDatabaseContext */}
        public void Test2() {/* Here i want to be able using MockDatabaseContext */}
        public void Test3() {/* Here i want to be able using MockDatabaseContext */}
    }
    /* Some other fixtures with tests that must have MockDatabaseContext */
}
```

Thanx

Comment: Make `MockDatabaseContext` field static deals the trick, but is it right solution?

Comment: You could then initialize the `TestContext` and pass the relevant detail there: https://nunit.org/index.php?p=testContext&r=2.6.4